# How can I get jQuery to call an event handler when an image actually appears on-screen?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events, dom

How can I use jQuery to trigger a callback of a JavaScript function when I scroll down and see a picture? I wish to delay loading certain images until they actually appear on-screen... Ideally, I'd be able to do something like:

```
$('#img#').look_on() { ...
```

So no images are loaded apart from those I have seen.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think this JQuery Event Plugin does what you need:

[**Element 'in view' Event Plugin**](http://remysharp.com/2009/01/26/element-in-view-event-plugin/)

> I've created an event that will trigger when the element is scrolled in to the viewport.

also, the LazyLoad Plugin seems to have a "viewport" selector for JQuqery: [**Here**](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/viewport).

Comment: A friend just asked me about something similar... +1 Now I don't have to do the research :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is some kind like what i searched for...
http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload